# Trying to add objects to Class and save info to Firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, class, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save new objects via a view controller in my app. However, I want these new objects to load when the app is logged into. I am using firebase to save data into a database, but how can I save an object and have it return when the app is logged into again? I am new-ish to programming, sorry for any potential confusion.

Here is where the goal information is read when the app has been logged into.

```
for i in 0 ... clientList.count - 1 {

screenHandle = ref?.child(organizationCode).child(clientList[i].name).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let clientStuffLoad = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]

    if clientStuffLoad["Goal 1 Description"] != nil {
        clientList[i].goal1 = clientStuffLoad["Goal 1"] as! String
    } else {
        clientList[i].goal1 = ""
    }
```

This is essentially what I have regarding adding a new member to the class `Client`:

```
@IBAction func addingClientSaveButton(_ sender: Any) {


        var client7 = Client(name: addingClientName.text!, 
                      goal1: addingClientGoal1.text!, goal2: 
                      addingClientGoal2.text!, 
                      goal3: addingClientGoal3.text!, 
                      isSelected: false, s: 1, 
                      ind: 1, targetBehavior1 : addingClientTB1.text!, 
                      targetBehavior2 : addingClientTB2.text!, 
                      targetBehavior3 : addingClientTB3.text!, 
                      targetBehavior1Info : addingClientTB1Info.text!, 
                      targetBehavior2Info : addingClientTB2Info.text!, 
                      targetBehavior3Info : addingClientTB3Info.text!)
```

but I would like the object name to read the client name input as opposed to `client7`

The second part to this is that I want a way to write this to the database, and be able to read it at log in so that I can use the properties of the class and add to it when adding a new client.

Comment: In general, if you attach and observer to a node in Firebase, it will automatically load the data on app start (assuming the function is called) and any time data changes within that node it will be called as well. Did you have a chance to review the Firebase Getting Started Guide [Listen for events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events). What part of the guide or your code are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Hi Jay thanks for the answer. I am hoping to add members to a class and save these objects as firebase entities. I guess I am looking for an example of how to add an object of an class with the press of a button, save the object into firebase, and then read the object and all its properties when the app is logged into again. Does this make sense? I'm not sure how to best add a new object programmatically without manually defining the object itself or save the properties via firebase.

Comment: That's a big question because it covers so many aspects; I hope the big answer helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a super broad question because it covers a lot of different aspects of working with Firebase; writing, reading, handling DataSnapshots etc. Also, I don't know what your data represents so I picked something for me to cover some of the aspects of working with Firebase.

There's no error checking but it works as is. I've commented along the way.

Firebase has no objects; just parent and child nodes. Everything can be thought of as key: value pairs like a dictionary. You cannot write an object or read an object. Only NSString, NSNumber, NSDictionary and the dreaded NSArray (or their Swift counterparts)

Let's start with a class - there's 100 ways to do this but I like classes to be responsible for their properties as well as accepting them and presenting them

```
class WineClass {
    var wine_key = ""
    var name = ""
    var varietal = ""

    //this is used when creating a new wine object before storing in firebase
    init(withName: String, andVarietal: String) {
        self.name = withName
        self.varietal = andVarietal
    }

    //this is used when we are loading data from firebase to create the wineclass object
    init(withSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        let wineName = withSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "wine_name").value as? String ?? "No Wine Name"

        let wineDict = withSnapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        let wineVarietal = wineDict["wine_varietal"] as? String ?? "No Wine Varietal"

        self.wine_key = withSnapshot.key //when we read a wine, this will be it's reference in case we want to update or delete it
        self.name = wineName
        self.varietal = wineVarietal
    }

    //this is use to create a dictionary of key:value pairs to be written to firebase
    func getWineDictForFirebase() -> [String: Any] {
        let d = [
            "wine_name": self.name,
            "wine_varietal": self.varietal
        ]

        return d
    }
}
```

Then, we need a class var to store the WineClass's. This would be for example a dataSource for a tableView

```
var wineArray = [WineClass]() //a class var array to store my wines
```

Then I will give you two buttons, one that populates and writes some wine to Firebase and then a second that read them in and prints to console

```
func button0() {
    self.writeWine(withName: "Scarecrow", andVarietal: "Red Blend")
    self.writeWine(withName: "Ghost Horse", andVarietal: "Cabernet Sauvignon")
    self.writeWine(withName: "Screaming Eagle", andVarietal: "Cabernet Sauvignon, Merlot, Cabernet Franc")
}

func button1() {
    self.readWines()
}
```

And then the function that accepts some strings as properites for each wine and writes them to Firebase

```
func writeWine(withName: String, andVarietal: String) {
   let newWine = WineClass(withName: withName, andVarietal: andVarietal) //create a new wine object

   let wineListRef = self.ref.child("wine_list") //get a reference to my firebase wine_list
   let thisWineRef = wineListRef.childByAutoId() //a new node for this wine
   let d = newWine.getWineDictForFirebase() //get the wine properties as a dictionary
   thisWineRef.setValue(d) //save it in firebase
}
```

and finally a function that reads in those wines, and prints their properties in console

```
func readWines() {
   let wineRef = self.ref.child("wine_list")
   wineRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in //we are reading in the entire wine node which will contain many child nodes
       let allWines = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] //cast each child node as a DataSnapshot & store in array
       for wineSnap in allWines { //iterate over each child node in the array
           let wine = WineClass(withSnapshot: wineSnap) //create a new wine, ensuring we also keep track of it's key
           self.wineArray.append(wine) //add to the array
       }

       for wine in self.wineArray  {
           print(wine.wine_key, wine.name, wine.varietal)
       }
   })
}
```

lastly, when button0 is clicked, our Firebase looks like this

```
wine_list
   -LhbjhkEC8o9TUISCjdw
      wine_name: "Scarecrow"
      wine_varietal: "Red Blend"
   -LhbjhkEC8o9TUISCjdx
      wine_name: "Ghost Horse"
      wine_varietal: "Cabernet Sauvignon"
   -LhbjhkEC8o9TUISCjdy
      wine_name: "Screaming Eagle"
      wine_varietal: "Cabernet Sauvignon, Merlot, Cabernet Franc"
```

and then the output when button1 is clicked

```
-LhbjhkEC8o9TUISCjdw Scarecrow Red Blend
-LhbjhkEC8o9TUISCjdx Ghost Horse Cabernet Sauvignon
-LhbjhkEC8o9TUISCjdy Screaming Eagle Cabernet Sauvignon, Merlot, Cabernet Franc
```

Note that self.ref is a reference to the root node of *my firebase* yours will need to reference *your* firebase.

Comment: I guess the part that I most need help on is that I want my save function (i.e. button0) to be able to save `newWine` with a name that the user chooses in a `UITextField`, therefore creating a new object with the user-specified name. Is that possible? I reference the array (similar to `wineArray`) a bit for my Table Views.

Comment: @staabi10 That's what the function does. As you can see in the button0 function we simply pass a string to the writeWine function `self.writeWine(withName: "Scarecrow"` and that's the name that is written to Firebase. You simple read the UITextField .text property e.g. `let text = myTextField.text` to obtain whatever the user typed and pass that string to the write function.

Comment: Okay thanks so much! I'll see what I can figure out (beginner status over here).